# How to plot a rootogram for a generalized poisson model with glmmmTMB package

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glmmtmb, iplots

I get errors whenever I try to run the line for the plot:

```
library(glmmTMB)
model.gp <- glmmTMB(Grav~Age+Site+Educ+Occupation+Maritalstat+HIVpos,family = "genpois",data=bo)
library("countreg")
countreg::rootogram(model.gp)
```

> Error in sqrt(as.vector(object)) :
> non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> In addition: Warning message:
> In rootogram.default(model.gp) : NAs introduced by coercion

I tried finding an appropriate function in the `glmmmTMB` package for plotting the `rootogram()` but I couldn't find one. I don't know if the problem could be the data or the package.

Comment: The problem is that no-one has implemented a method for `glmmTMB` objects; the current package only implements methods for `glm`, `gamlss`, etc.. It might not be too hard to write up a method, but it's also not entirely trivial ...